# Creating a column which values are TRUE, if other column moves from FALSE to TRUE, by group

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I have data as follows:

```
library(stringi)

datfake <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0, 3000))
names(datfake)[1] <- "Inc"
datfake$type <- sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE)
datfake$province <- stri_rand_strings(100, 1, "[A-P]")
datfake$non_response <- sample(rep(c("TRUE","FALSE"),each=50),100,replace=FALSE)

           Inc type province non_response
1    693.55581    R        H        FALSE
2   2539.40434    X        B        FALSE
3    990.16946    W        I        FALSE
4    208.33514    W        I         TRUE
5   1600.92130    X        P        FALSE
```

I would like to create a column `new_col`, which is TRUE, if the `type` makes the switch from `FALSE`, to `TRUE` (and only that way around). I thought to do:

```
setDT(datfake)
datfake <- setDT(datfake)[non_response != shift(non_response), new_col:= TRUE,  by=type]
```

The code runs, but there are two problems:

1. It does not stick to the type.
2. The way I wrote it, it is also `TRUE` if it goes from `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

   ```
            Inc type province non_response           new_col
   1:  693.55581    R        H        FALSE               NA
   2: 2539.40434    X        B        FALSE               NA
   3:  990.16946    W        I        FALSE               NA
   4:  208.33514    W        I         TRUE             TRUE
   5: 1600.92130    X        P        FALSE             TRUE
   ```

Desired output:

In line 4, there is a change in non_response, for type `W`, from `FALSE`, to `TRUE`, so in that case, `new_col` should be TRUE.

In all other case it should be false.

So the last line in the previous output is not correct, because `X` in line 2 is also `FALSE`. So where my attempt has `new_col` `TRUE`, in line 5 it should be false.

```
         Inc type province non_response           new_col
1:  693.55581    R        H        FALSE               NA
2: 2539.40434    X        B        FALSE               NA
3:  990.16946    W        I        FALSE               NA
4:  208.33514    W        I         TRUE             TRUE
5: 1600.92130    X        P        FALSE             FALSE
```

How should I write this?

Comment: What is your expected output in your example?

Comment: @Maël I have tried to clarify with desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```r
datfake[, new_col:= non_response != shift(non_response), by=type]
```